# Azure Front Door SSL Certificate Update

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-front-door

I have setup a Azure Front Door on top of my Function APIs. I have setup a custom domain and SSL certificate for the same. The certificate was bought from Azure and was set to auto renew. After a year , the certificate has got expired in the front door. The app service certificate was auto-renewed but the Front door did not get the update. I had to manually go to the site to update the certificate with the new secret from the key vault. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the certificate be updated automatically. Please advice.

Comment: Please send me an email to _AzCommunity[at]microsoft[dot]com ATTN Ryan including your subscription id so we can look more closely at this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below link, which says:

> Certificate will auto renew within 90 days. But in case if it does not renews then even with less than 60/ 30 days, then need to file a ticket to the support team

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/75126/azure-front-door-automatic-ssl-certificate-renewal.html